# Xcode 6 GM can not simulate location with iOS 8 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6

I set location with Xcode's "Simulate Location" button, and iOS simulator's "Debug>Location>Custom Location", these are not work.
And the Maps.app can not get location too.

Of course, I update the code for iOS 8's CLLocationManager. such as "requestAlwaysAuthorization" and "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"

Comment: In my case location is *only* working for iphone 6plus simulator. why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your Scheme,

1. In the Options tab make sure you tick Allow Location Simulation.
2. Select a default location (optional).
3. Reset Simulator's contents and settings.
   It's work for me.

P/S: You may need restart the Xcode IDE.

[image]

Comment: I'd configured the options and default locations. Resetting the contents got me over the finish line. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my temporary solution:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self locationManager:manager didUpdateLocations:@[[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:<#(CLLocationDegrees)#> longitude:<#(CLLocationDegrees)#>]]];
    return;

    // Something you should do when Xcode not crazy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issues in XCode6, but now it works fine in Xcode 6.1